# Problem about program code included in LaTeX

Tags: code, matlab, fancyvrb

1. I have some Matlab code which I
   would like to include in my LaTeX
   document.

   I use [fancyvrb](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ctan.org%2Ftex-archive%2Fmacros%2Flatex%2Fcontrib%2Ffancyvrb%2F&rct=j&q=fancyvrb&ei=q35tTdr-CoWdlge83qGIBQ&usg=AFQjCNFxGXA501Sbl6RFiNtia0UTnJ8YnA&sig2=yIPeU-2YAjVfrQ_FyDJKIw&cad=rja) package, based on
   which I define a new environment
   called code. An complete and minimum
   example is:

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
   \usepackage{fancyvrb}
   \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small}
   \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{example}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{code}
   addpath('~/plot'); 
   \end{code}
   \end{document}
   ```

   However, in the created pdf file, if
   I copy the code and
   paste it in Matlab command window,
   Matlab will complaint about the
   single quote is not the one used in
   Matlab. I was wondering why and how
   to solve the problem?
2. To generalize, I also hope to know
   if there may possibly be other
   characters besides single quote that
   can cause such error? Not only in
   Matlab but also other programming
   languages?
3. Also, I was wondering if my way of including code in LaTeX by using fancyvrb is the best? Do you have other nice ways to recommend?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few years ago I wrote a book about the use Matlab, and I used the `listings` package for all included code.  This allows lots of options: escape to (La)TeX, coloured backgrounds, frames etc.

I set up my listings with

```
\lstset{language={},
  keepspaces=true,
  xleftmargin=\parindent,
  xrightmargin=\parindent,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  frame=single,
  framesep=2mm,
  framerule=0pt,
  columns=flexible,
  backgroundcolor=\color[gray]{0.9}}
```

and then called it with

```
\begin{lstlisting}
function sc(n)

for i = 1:n
    disp([i, i^2, i^3])
end  
\end{lstlisting}
```

I have also been using it for student notes.